# No headers when using Mock RestEasy framework

Tags: spring, unit-testing, rest, resteasy

I am trying to use the server-side resteasy mock framework to make a GET request however when trying to retrieve the header from the server code it simply doesn't exist.

Below is the Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:base-spring-context.xml" }, loader = DelegatingSmartContextLoader.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class TestClass {

// Sets up RESTEasy processors to test @Provider classes
@Configuration
static class ContextConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public Dispatcher getDispatcher() {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(getSpringResourceFactory());
        return dispatcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanProcessor getRSPostProcessor() {
        SpringBeanProcessor processor = new SpringBeanProcessor(getDispatcher(), getDispatcher().getRegistry(),
                getDispatcher().getProviderFactory());
        return processor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceFactory getSpringResourceFactory() {
        SpringResourceFactory noDefaults = new SpringResourceFactory("restClass", context,
                RestClass.class);
        return noDefaults;
    }
}

@Autowired
Dispatcher dispatcher;

@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextDataMap().put(HttpServletRequest.class, new MockHttpServletRequest(servletContext));
}

@Test
public void testRest() throws URISyntaxException, ECUNotFoundException {
    MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/")
            .header("someHeader", "VALUE")
            .accept("application/myValue+XML");
    logger.info("HEADERS: {}",request.getHttpHeaders().getRequestHeader("someHeader"));
    MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();
    dispatcher.invoke(request, response);
    logger.info("Got response: \n\tStatus: '{}'\n\tResponse body: '{}'",response.getStatus(),new String(response.getOutput()));
}
}
```

Here is the method the Rest method gets triggered from RestClass

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/myValue+XML")
@GZIP
public Response getMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String header = request.getHeader("someHeader");
        logger.info("HEADER NAME: {}","someHeader");
        if (header == null || header.isEmpty()) {
            logger.warn("the header must be present in the request");
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
```

The issue here is that the Rest method does not receive the header. It is null however when the printout from the test method clearly shows that the header is set.

Can anybody help understanding why this happens.